# Markov inequality for inequality in other direction

Tags: probability

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

Given a non-negative integer-valued random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{E}(X)=50$ and $Var(X)=25$, bound $\mathbb{P}[X < 30]$ with Markovs inequality.

I know that Markov inequality is defined as follows:

For a non-negative integer-valued randomm variable $X$,
$\mathbb{P}[X\geq a] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]/a$ for any $a \> 0$.

I tried the following:
$\mathbb{P}[X < 30] = 1-\mathbb{P}[X \geq 30] \geq 1- \mathbb{E}(X)/30 = 1-50/30=-2/3$.
But this gives me a completely useless bound, as any probability is at least $0$.

Is there any other variant of Markov which I could apply to get a usefull result?
Or is there any trick that I could use?

Comment: One possibility might be to use the proof of Chebyshev's inequality and apply Markov's inequality to $Y=(X-\mathbb E[X])^2$.